# Trouble storing responses of AT commands

Tags: c++, embedded, at-command

I'm using MSP430 and SIM900 modules to send and receive SMS. When I receive a SMS, I want to read the message and store the information in a variable. I even want to store the sender number.

AT+CPBR=1 // This command will display the first message in the buffer

//Function to store the response serially

```
String str = "";
void getstr()
{
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    str += inChar;                    //str is of String Datatype 
    if(inChar == '\n')
    {
      Serial.println(str);
    }
  }
}
```

I have seen many similar codes to store the response but the response is not being stored.

I'm using Energia IDE and Embedded C++ programming language

Comment: Might help if you mention what compiler and programming language that is used.

Comment: What type is `str? Is it a std::string? What is its content before the `println`?